# html/PHP - Form POST empty

Tags: php, html, forms

I am wondering where my mistake is.
I've been looking at different solutions on why the $_POST is empty, and none have come up with an answer as to why it is happening.

i have tried the following changes in HTML
method="GET" and method="POST" - neither works
action="test.php" / action="localhost/test.php" / action="c:\xampp\htdocs\test.php"

Here is the HTML Form code

```
<form name="Driftslog" action="localhost/test.php" method="POST">
    Init: <input type="text" id="Init" size="5" maxlength="5" autocomplete="on" required> <br></br>
    LID: <input type="text" id="LID" size="8" maxlength="8" required><br></br>
    Ticket-ID: <input type="text" id="TicketID" size="20" maxlength="15" required><br></br>
    Kunde: <input type="text" id="Kunde" size="25" maxlength="50" required><br></br>
    Start tid: <input type="datetime" id="StartTid" size="15" value="" required> <br></br>
    Slut tid: <input type="datetime" id="SlutTid" size="15" value="" required><br></br\
    Tilkald <input type="checkbox" id="Tilakd"><br></br>
    Planlagt <input type="checkbox" id="Planlagt"><br></br>
    Andet <input type="checkbox" id="Andet"><br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Opret">
</form>
```

and here is my PHP file test.php
in this PHP file i tried various changes.
i commented out the entire IF section and just tried to print the variable to see what was in it, using var_dump($_POST) /print_r and a for each loop.
all came back empty

it is like the HTML does not pass the data to the php file

The only thing that works in the php file is the last echo and page redirect

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $Init = trim($_POST["Init"]);
  $LID = trim($_POST["LID"]);
  $TicketID = trim($_POST["TicketID"]);
  $Kunde = trim($_POST["Kunde"]);
  $StarttTid = trim($_POST["StartTid"]);
  $SlutTid = trim($_POST["SlutTid"]);
  $data = [ $Init, $LID, $TicketID, $Kunde, $StartTid, $SlutTid, "\n"];

$f = fopen("db.csv","a");
fputcsv($f, $data);
fclose($f);

print $TicketID;
} 

echo "oprettet med success";
header("Refresh:3; url=http://localhost"); 
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem -**

Your form values do not make it to your PHP.

**Solution -**

- Updated if statement to check for "REQUEST_METHOD"
- Use "name" in form fields. You can not rely on ID.

**Example -**

***index.html -***

```
 <form name="Driftslog" action="localhost/test.php" method="POST">
        Init: <input type="text" id="Init" name="Init" size="5" maxlength="5" autocomplete="on" required> <br></br>
        LID: <input type="text" id="LID" name="LID" size="8" maxlength="8" required><br></br>
        Ticket-ID: <input type="text" id="TicketID" name="TicketID"  size="20" maxlength="15" required><br></br>
        Kunde: <input type="text" id="Kunde" name="Kunde" size="25" maxlength="50" required><br></br>
        Start tid: <input type="datetime" id="StartTid" name="StartTid" size="15" value="" required> <br></br>
        Slut tid: <input type="datetime" id="SlutTid" name="SlutTid" size="15" value="" required><br></br\
        Tilkald <input type="checkbox" id="Tilakd" name="Tilakd"><br></br>
        Planlagt <input type="checkbox" id="Planlagt" name="Planlagt"><br></br>
        Andet <input type="checkbox" id="Andet" name="Andet"><br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Opret">
    </form>
```

***test.php -***

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $Init = trim($_POST["Init"]);
  $LID = trim($_POST["LID"]);
  $TicketID = trim($_POST["TicketID"]);
  $Kunde = trim($_POST["Kunde"]);
  $StarttTid = trim($_POST["StartTid"]);
  $SlutTid = trim($_POST["SlutTid"]);
  $data = [ $Init, $LID, $TicketID, $Kunde, $StartTid, $SlutTid, "\n"];

$f = fopen("db.csv","a");
fputcsv($f, $data);
fclose($f);

print $TicketID;
} 

echo "oprettet med success";
header("Refresh:3; url=http://localhost"); 
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I updated and tested this. It works.

Comment: This actually worked - changed the ID tag to name, populated the array in the test.php
Thanks for the input :)
But the other 2 was correct aswell. i was missing the name-tag on submit aswell

Comment: Notice that I changed the if to check for request method.

Comment: yeah i noticed, but it works with the IF aswell.. but copied over your solution for good measure :) 

i am learning how to code both HTML and php for a maintenance log for work. 
and this was the only thing so far, i couldnt get to work

Answer (score 0):

In your `input` fields you are missing the `name=''` attributes

Comment: Thanks for the help here..

it was part of the solution - i had to change the ID tags to name and add the name tag to the submit button aswell

Comment: You did not need to change `id` to `name`.. you could've utilized the `id` in JS or CSS if you needed those. However the POST in Form needs explicitly the `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

To read fields from the post request the input fields must have the `name` attribute.

Change your HTML to something like this:

```
<form name="Driftslog" action="localhost/test.php" method="POST">
    Init: <input type="text" id="Init" name="Init" size="5" maxlength="5" autocomplete="on" required> <br></br>
    LID: <input type="text" id="LID" name="LID" size="8" maxlength="8" required><br></br>
    Ticket-ID: <input type="text" id="TicketID" name="TicketID" size="20" maxlength="15" required><br></br>
    Kunde: <input type="text" id="Kunde" name="Kunde" size="25" maxlength="50" required><br></br>
    Start tid: <input type="datetime" id="StartTid" name="StartTid" size="15" value="" required> <br></br>
    Slut tid: <input type="datetime" id="SlutTid" name="SlutTid" size="15" value="" required><br></br\
    Tilkald <input type="checkbox" id="Tilakd" name="Tilakd"><br></br>
    Planlagt <input type="checkbox" id="Planlagt" name="Planlagt"><br></br>
    Andet <input type="checkbox" id="Andet" name="Andet"><br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Opret">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here..

it was part of the solution - i had to change the ID tags to name and add the name tag to the submit button aswell